# How to load script when src url is in angular scope?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get some custom script to load that is stored in the database depending on some logic i have on client side. My problem is how to get  to work.

My controller:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('youshareApp')
    .controller('ShareCtrl',['$scope','$routeParams' ,'Projectservice',function     ($scope,$routeParams,Projectservice) {
 $scope.projectId=$routeParams.projectId;
 $scope.model.url="/api/v1/project/code/"+$scope.projectId;
...

}]);
```

My view:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ShareCtrl" style="margin-top: 50px;" >
<h3>You are currently contributing to : </h3>

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="col-md-6"><label class="lead">{{model.name}}</label></div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="col-md-6"><p class="lead" >{{model.description}}</p></div>
</div>
<script ng-src={{model.url}} />
</div>
```

How could i make this work?

I also tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028792/loading-an-external-script-using-script-src-in-angular)

With this in the template:

```
    <div html-bind-unsafe='html'></div>
```

And this in the Controller:

```
    $scope.html='<script src="'+$scope.model.url+'" />';
```

Comment: @Patrick Evans thanks for the edit i didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the url to be safe. You can do that by reading a bit on it here : 
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl

another thing that could be happening is that you are not using ng-src.

Comment: I don't think it's a same origin policy issue since its the same host/port also since it's a script tag even outside urls should be allowed.

Comment: But just to be shure i tried it like : `$scope.html=$sce.trustAsHtml('<script ng-src="http://localhost:9000/api/v1/project/code/lehel" ></script>');` but still not working